# I want hover text with image

Tags: html, css, image

I found some piece of code here and change it a little bit for my needs.

I want to create a list of items and when you hover each line I want to show image on the right side but without sliding text up/down regarding shown images.

This is my code so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/nikolaf/p65vwbeL/6/

```css
.papers {
}

.hoverinfo {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hoverinfo .eachpaper {
  display: none;
  color: #000000;
}

.hoverinfo:hover .eachpaper {
  margin-left:115px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="papers">

<div class="hoverinfo"> my image 1
    <div class="eachpaper"><img src="https://yogifil.la/175/200" /></div>
</div>


<div class="hoverinfo"> my image 2
    <div class="eachpaper"><img src="https://yogifil.la/190/234" /></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fiddle you gave looks a bit finicky. You may be better off creating a list using ul/li to the left and using :hover to display the images to the right. Just a suggestion!

Have a look at this:

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  min-width: 250px
}

.pix li.image span {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.pix li img.image {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 150px;
  top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

li:hover img.image {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pix">
  <li><span>image1</span><img class="image" src="https://yogifil.la/175/200"></li>
  <li><span>image2</span><img class="image" src="https://yogifil.la/190/234"></li>
  <li><span>image3></span><img class="image" src="your source"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: very nice, thanks Rachel, now I will try to add what Moose suggested below

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle.Only you need to use position properties to fix this issue.

```css
.papers {
}

.hoverinfo {
  position:relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hoverinfo .eachpaper {
  position:absolute;
  display: none;
  color: #000000;
}

.hoverinfo:hover .eachpaper {
  margin-left:115px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="papers">

<div class="hoverinfo"> my image 1
    <div class="eachpaper"><img src="https://yogifil.la/175/200" /></div>
</div>


<div class="hoverinfo"> my image 2
    <div class="eachpaper"><img src="https://yogifil.la/190/234" /></div>
</div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/p65vwbeL/16/

Thanks.

Comment: @Nikola Filo, If you need any help, let me know. thanks.

Comment: That's perfect, but one q, can we somehow create that image is always loaded for example 8px on the right side after my word end?

Understand what I am saying?

Comment: @NikolaFilo, Do you want display one of images when page loads first time?

Comment: No, that is not necessary at the moment, but thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can also trying this:

```
    .hoverinfo {
       cursor: pointer;
       position:relative;
     }

     .hoverinfo .eachpaper {
        opacity:0;
        color: #000000;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:100px;
        transition:0.3s ease-in-out;
     }

     .hoverinfo:hover .eachpaper {
      opacity:1;
     }
```

the opacity adds a smoother transition as well which is always nice!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nikolaf/p65vwbeL/41/
Final result. Thanks everyone!